# Javascript edit text in selection via Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a simple bookmarklet (bookmark with javascript applet) that will get the selected text, reverse it, and then change it on screen. For example, if the user selects some text, say, the word hello, and then activates this bookmarklet, the text would then turn into olleh. So far I have the following:

```
javascript:
function getSelectedText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
    return text;
}
var selectedText = getSelectedText();
var textArray = selectedText.split("");
var reverseArray = textArray.reverse();
var reverseText = reverseArray.join("");
alert(reverseText);
```

I got the `getSelectedText()` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text). At the end, the bookmarklet simply alerts the reversed text. How do you make it so that it actually replaces the text on the page? Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the end:

```
var nodeValue = window.getSelection().baseNode.nodeValue;
window.getSelection().baseNode.nodeValue = nodeValue.replace(selectedText, reverseText);
```

**EDIT**

Use selection offset for reversing in the right place, `str.replace` only replaces the first occurrence of the word, and it can be wrong for common words such as "the".

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var start = selection.anchorOffset;
var end = selection.focusOffset;
var nodeValue = selection.baseNode.nodeValue;
var newValue = nodeValue.slice(0, start) + reverseText + nodeValue.slice(end);
window.getSelection().baseNode.nodeValue = newValue;
```

Comment: This sort-of works. I seem to remember having tried something that produced the same result, which replaces all of the text on the page. I think that this would work were it put into a webpage with a `<script>` tag. However, since bookmarklets are run after the webpage is loaded, this replaces the entire DOM with the reversed text.

Comment: Wrap your bookmarklet with a closure like this: `javascript: (function() { /* code */ })()`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I always forget to wrap my javascript in a closure.

Comment: @kungfushark see updated answer, you should use offsets instead